# How to get every pann gesture that happens

Tags: xamarin.forms, swipe, slide, pan

I have a pretty simple question but I can't find any answer about it.

I have an app and I would like to get a function called, each time that a **Pan/Swipe/Slide** gesture happen.

I know how does the layouts are organized, so it means I can't add a gesture on the main layout, but at the same time, it seems creepy to add this gesture to each elements...

Any idea?

Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find something which isn't that bad, which can also raise an event or call a given `Action<>`

```
public class PanContainer : ContentView
{
    private double x, y;

    public PanContainer()
    {
        var panGesture = new PanGestureRecognizer();
        panGesture.PanUpdated += OnPanUpdated;
        GestureRecognizers.Add(panGesture);
        BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent;
    }

    private double valueX;
    private double valueY;

    private void OnPanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.TotalX == 0 && e.TotalX != valueX)
            Debug.WriteLine("The X pan value is [{0}]", valueX);
        valueX = e.TotalX;
        if (e.TotalY == 0 && e.TotalY != valueX)
            Debug.WriteLine("The Y pan value is [{0}]", valueY);
        valueY = e.TotalY;
    }
}
```

Just use it like it

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="Black">
        <component:PanContainer AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 0.5, 1, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">

        </component:PanContainer>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

and don't forget to include `xmlns:component="clr-namespace:NAMESPACE.Sources.Components;assembly=NightLine"`

---

If you wanna raise an event or call a function, do it from `private void OnPanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e) { .. }`

Comment: great, it looks they added more gesture recognizers. when last time I did it they had only touch/click recognizer.

Answer (score 0):

Make custom Page renderer and add gestures there.

Here is an example on iOS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Knok;
using Knok.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(SearchEventsPage), typeof(SearchEventsPageRenderer))]

namespace Knok.iOS
{
    class SearchEventsPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer swipeLeftGestureRecognizer, swipeRightGestureRecognizer;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null) 
            {
                if (swipeLeftGestureRecognizer != null)
                    NativeView.RemoveGestureRecognizer(swipeLeftGestureRecognizer);
                if (swipeRightGestureRecognizer != null)
                    NativeView.RemoveGestureRecognizer(swipeRightGestureRecognizer);
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {

                swipeLeftGestureRecognizer = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer(_ => 
                    {
                        ((SearchEventsPage)Element).OnSwipeLeft();
                    })
                {
                    Direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
                };
                NativeView.AddGestureRecognizer(swipeLeftGestureRecognizer);

                swipeRightGestureRecognizer = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer(() =>
                    {
                        ((SearchEventsPage)Element).OnSwipeRight();
                    })
                {
                    Direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
                };
                NativeView.AddGestureRecognizer(swipeRightGestureRecognizer);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

where OnSwipeLeft and OnSwipeRight defined in SearchEventsPage as

```
public async void OnSwipeLeft()
{
}
```

Comment: I had this idea and began to do it, however, it seems to be a lot of work for finally nothing that complicated, doesn't it?